# Is it safe to use JQuery event names as class names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm testing a remote site and the click event for an element isn't working in some Windows environments for Internet Explorer and Safari.

I've noticed the class name for elements that are clickable is "click". So the event is defined like this:

```
$('.click').click(function() {
```

Before I delve deeper into other possible causes, does this look safe?

Thanks
Sean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely, jQuery/Javascript event names are totally unrelated to CSS class names until the two are paired by a developer (or a framework, however in such instances the classes are typically prefixed).

With that in mind, you may want actually to move away from using such generic '*event-centric*' class names, CSS after all is '*style centric*', if you are identifying clickable elements, you could instead give them the attribute `data-clickable='true'` and change your selector to `$('[data-clickable=true]')`. By doing so you maintain the distinct seperation between style (CSS), content(HTML) and function (JS) deemed to be best practice. That said, to go back to your question, it really doesnt matter in the way you ask.

Comment: +1 for the insight - actually, in some years we'll just have `.tap` and/or `.touch`. Or `.lookAt`, so don't let presentation mess with behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it does look safe and *is* safe. There is no harm in using event names as class names, until you don't get confused ;)

Both are different. CSS cannot conflict with JS. So, it is safe to use what you're using.